# Flutter Bloc Login

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have a small obstacle when logging in using dart language (flutter), I login by requesting username and password to API but the wrong username / password can still login. That's why?

Sorry I tried to post source code but always error post quest, therefore I send via screenshots.

Source Code Login Page :
[image: SS Login Page]

And Source Code Login Bloc :
[image: SS Login Bloc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login page, the below line needs to move to a place where you handle state changes

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()))
```

There should be a place where you have a listener or some kind of stream builder that handles the state change. So you should have something like,

```
...
builder: (BuildContext context, LoginState state){
    ...
    if(state is LoginSuccess){
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()));
    }
    else if(state is LoginFailed){
       // Show a snackbar with the reason for the failure. 
       // You could use scaffold or an external library depending on your preference
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: if (state is LoginSuccess) {
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard()));
                          } else if (state is LoginFailed) {
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
                          } 



I have adjusted the code above but else LoginFailed error in LoginPage(). can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Because you navigating user after login request. You are adding event (`LoginSubmit`) to BLoC, and then, without operation check, navigate to Dashboard. You need to check auth, and if auth is success, navigate to next screen.